# How to use sequential UUID primary key for range query by date

Tags: mysql, index, uuid

I'm using a sequential timebased GUID as my primary key in MySQL 5.6 in a transaction table with over 1 billion rows. The application is written in JAVA and GUID is generated as described here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JugHome

The question that I have is whether or not it is possible to range query the data by date without additional indexes? I've seen this question and the answer which states that this is somehow possible: [Sequential GUID or bigint for 'huge' database table PK](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31137/sequential-guid-or-bigint-for-huge-database-table-pk)

Existing implementation is using Type 1 UUID, [as described here](https://www.famkruithof.net/guid-uuid-timebased.html). Then I came across [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/), which describes efficient way to save the UUID, by re-organizing its contents.

The question that I have is whether searching by such UUID for a date range (and how it can be done) will be efficient, in other words, is it worth to save storage space by not adding index on the Date column?

Comment: You may want to include some details on how the GUIDs are generated in your question, instead of asking folks to read the IETF specification. To answer your question, yes, it is possible if you can somehow derive date values from your GUIDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for such is [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid), but it only works for "Type 1" UUIDs.  It's a matter of shuffling the bits around.  And while you are at it, `BINARY(16)` is more compact than `VARCHAR(36)` or whatever you have now.

**More**

By rearranging the bits of a type-1 UUID, you can take advantage of "locality of reference" when using an index on it.  For example, if you had News articles.  Users tend to look at recent articles and not touch the old ones.  New rows will be cached; old ones will drift into oblivion.

A suitably rearranged `UUID` would provide the equivalent of `ORDER BY datetime`.

Comment: Yes, existing implementation is using Type 1 UUID, as described here: https://www.famkruithof.net/guid-uuid-timebased.html
Then I came accross this article, which describes efficient way to save the UUID, by re-organizing its contents: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/

the question that I have is whether searching by such UUID for a date range (and how it can be done) will be efficient, in other words, is it worth to save storage space by not adding index on the Date column?

Comment: I edited my answer to address your question.